# Unresolved reference startKoin in android

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

I have added all the dependencies of Koin to the android app, but I am not able to use the references. How to resolve this

**KoinVersion**

```
ext.koin_version = "3.5.1"
```

**Dependencies used**

```
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-core:$koin_version"
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-scope:$koin_version"
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:$koin_version"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no version 3.5.1 for these dependencies, for similar cases you can find the issues on the *Build* tab after syncing with Gradle:

[image]

You can try using `koin-bom` dependency instead as follows:

```
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-bom:$koin_version"
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-core"
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android"
```

I excluded `koin-androidx-scope` and `koin-androidx-viewmodel` as it looks like they are not supported anymore. Their latest updates are from [May 2021](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.insert-koin/koin-androidx-viewmodel), and they are not mentioned on the [official website](https://insert-koin.io/docs/setup/koin).